# (How) should I rebalance classes when playing a campaign with infinite long rests?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew

I'm preparing a D&D 5e campaign with the ability to reset time as a core mechanic. As the players will start each time loop fully rested and can choose to reset time when desired, they will start each day fully healed and with all their resources available.

This will make them pretty strong for the first encounters, before they will probably decide to reset time and use their new knowledge to skip the challenges ahead. (Something I will design for, because no one wants to replay each situation again in every loop.)

I'm okay with the party being strong altogether. (I can just increase the difficulty of fights slightly, for instance.) But I am afraid, that some classes might overshadow other classes as e.g., I've read that casters are generally stronger than martial classes when they have too many long rests available to restock their spell slots.

Questions:

- Is this actually a problem, or do you think this won't matter that much in the end?
- If it is a problem, what would be some good rules to rebalance the classes that would be stronger with more resources? (E.g. "Make casters only have 1/2 of their spell slots available, rounding up.")

Comment: I have closed your first question as a duplicate.  If you think it is _not_ a duplicate, please explain why and it may be unclosed.  Your second question seems opinion-based.  Please read [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/what-questions-are-subjective-and-what-does-good-subjective-bad-subjective) about 'good subjective' and ask your second question as a new post, paying careful attention to defining what qualifies as 'good rules to rebalance the classes'.  What, specifically, do you want these rules modifications to do and how will you evaluate them?